# Personal-practice tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I've recently created the tag [personal-practice](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/personal-practice) and did a bit of retagging.

Was that a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

Well I guess I thought it was a good idea but i just wanted to open it up a little. The [practice](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/practice) I think has become a bit of a dumping ground so I wanted to tidy it up 
a bit

I think there was two concepts in the [practice](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/practice) tag. The sort of question like

1. [Why do monks shave their heads](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/2216/is-there-any-significance-to-shaving-the-head) type of question which I think is a general question about Buddhist practice
2. And the [Hey why do I get pins and needles](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/5652/intense-pins-and-needles) type question which is about some personal experience that the OP wants us to dig into.

So I split of another tag [personal-practice](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/personal-practice) which covers the second concept. I wanted to capture the more subjective nature of these questions. Also I'm aware that some people might not like this kind of question and I separate tag would enable them to screen it.

I guess one could see this as a meta tag like [beginner](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) but honestly I see [personal-practice](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/personal-practice) as been an identifier for the content of the tag.

Just what I think though.